# Tools for working with xtrabackup files?

Tags: mysql, backup, hadoop, xtrabackup

I have database backups in xtrabackup format. I would like to load them into hive without restoring to a mysql instance and use sqoop to then do the transfer.

If there are libraries to work with the format I can probably write my own utility to load the data into hive. I'm also more than happy to receive other suggestions on how to do that.

Comment: You'd go to all the trouble of writing something to do that when all you have to do is spin up an instance of MySQL? Sounds interesting, but unless you are a student doing this out of interest,  I fail to see what benefit you could derive from such a strategy. The time you'd spend doing this (debugging - plus who's going to provide support?).

Comment: The benefit is speed and correctness. Sqoop is really the worst.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools to extract data from XtraBackup data files. But don't forget about a redo log. Without it the Xtrabackup copy is incomplete. To make the backup usable you have to apply the redo log which means you need to restore the backup.

I would look at mydumper or mysqldump with `-T` option and then upload the dumps to hive.

Comment: do you have a linke to those tools? `There are tools to extract data from XtraBackup data files`. Thanks